# How can I access this value in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, object, yaml

Completely new to Ruby, looking through docs and can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I have an object and I'm trying to dig down into it to access something. The object tweets[0] looks like this...

```
--- !ruby/object:Twitter::Tweet
attrs:
  :created_at: Wed Apr 10 00:58:21 +0000 2013
  :user:
    :location: ''
    :entities:
      :description:
        :urls: []
    :protected: false
  :geo:
  :entities:
    :hashtags:
    - :text: adult
      :indices:
      - 34
      - 40
    :urls: []
    :user_mentions: []
    :media:
      :indices:
      - 41
      - 63
      :url: http:t.co/i-need-this-image
      :type: photo
      :sizes:
        :thumb:
          :w: 150
          :h: 150
          :resize: crop
        :small:
          :w: 340
          :h: 453
          :resize: fit
        :medium:
          :w: 600
          :h: 800
          :resize: fit
        :large:
          :w: 768
          :h: 1024
          :resize: fit
```

I've tried so many different ways, none of them seem to be working correctly. In order to dump them out I've been using

```
puts YAML::dump(tweets[0])
--
puts YAML::dump(tweets[0].media) # returns the media method correctly
puts YAML::dump(tweets[0]['media']) # also seems to do it
puts YAML::dump(tweets[0].media.url) # idk
puts YAML::dump(tweets[0]['media']['url']) # I feel like this should work but it doesn't
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
require 'yaml'
tweets = YAML.load_file('test.yml') # this file contains a copy of the YAML
p tweets["attrs"][:entities][:media][:url] # "http:t.co/i-need-this-image"
```

Comment: ah, that's the syntax I was looking for. It works up to [:media], then when I add [:url] it throws the error => Liquid Exception: can't convert Symbol into Integer in index.html

Comment: That's strange, if I do this: `YAML::dump(tweets["attrs"][:entities][:media][:url])` I get this: `"--- http:t.co/i-need-this-image\n...\n"`.

Comment: So, this ended up working for me. I don't know why, or how...but it works... `tweets[i].media[0].url`